# Why is it not a Function React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wrote this code and i made the constructor methode

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this._addTodo = this._addTodo.bind(this);
  this._searchBar = this._searchBar.bind(this);
  this._removeTodo = this._removeTodo.bind(this);
}
```

then this function :

```js
_addTodo() {
  var data = test.map(x => [x.name, x.price, ]);
  var searchField = $('.objectName').val();
  data.map(function(theTrue) {
    if (searchField === theTrue[0]) 
    {
      $('.objects')
      .append('<div class = "box"> <i className = "hvhv">' + $('.quantityObject').val() + ' </i><i> ' + $('.objectName').val() + ' </i><i> ' + $('.priceValue').text() + '</i><button onClick={this._removeTodo()} className="removeTodo">Remove</button></div>');
    }
  })
}
```

when i call this function everything go fine

```
<button className="addItem" onClick={this._addTodo}>Add</button>
```

but when i called this function  :

```
_removeTodo(){
   console.log('work');
   $( ".box" ).remove();
}
```

It is written :

> Uncaught TypeError: this._removeTodo is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
>   onclick @ (index):1

Comment: You either use jquery to manipulate DOM or React, not both. Not saying they cannot be used together, but using them together: 1. Confuses beginners 2. Is a sign something is being done in a reeeeeeeeeeally wrong way.

Comment: @zerkms So how can i fix this ?

Comment: You cannot fix it, you need to reimplement it from scratch using React (if you're supposed to use react).

Comment: @zerkms is right. using jQuery in React defeats the purpose completely. 
That entire div element in the map function can be done inreact in a much cleaner format :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactjs using virtual dom, this create a object tree based on jsx and render on UI. Here DOM manipulation completely not suggested using jQuery. If you want to show data based on condition, do it on reactjs objects like state or props, Don't try to remove element using jQuery.

Here's a example how to add and remove element using only Reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todo: [],
    name: '',
    quantity: '',
    price: '',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this._addTodo = this._addTodo.bind(this);
    this._removeTodo = this._removeTodo.bind(this);
  }

  _addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { todo, name, quantity, price } = this.state

    const newTodo = {
      name,
      quantity,
      price,
      id: Date.now(),
    }

    this.setState({
      todo: [...todo, newTodo],
    })
  }

  _removeTodo(item) {
    const { todo } = this.state

    let index

    index = todo.findIndex(x => x.id === item.id)
    todo.splice(index, 1)

    this.setState({
      todo,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this._addTodo}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.setState({name: e.target.value})} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={e => this.setState({quantity: e.target.value})} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Price" value={this.state.price} onChange={e => this.setState({price: e.target.value})} />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this._addTodo}>Add</button>
        </form>
        <hr />
        <div>
          {this.state.todo.map(item => (
            <div className="box">
              <i className="hvhv">{item.quantity}</i>
              <i> {item.name} </i>
              <i>{item.price}</i>
              <button type="button" onClick={() => this._removeTodo(item)} className="removeTodo">Remove</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```